# Can't find where my MongoDB is storing files

Tags: python, mongodb, tweepy

I have lost probably one whole day to this problem. I can't find where my MongoDB stores data. it's not in user/data/db. I ran ps -xa | grep mongod and it's not in any of the directories listed there. When I start mongodb and execute show dbs I get a list of empty databases. No idea where on hard drive they are. At this point I have no clue what is happening. The code I am running is taken from another web site and is working. It shows that elements are being inserted into db. I tried everything that I know of and nothing is working. Here is the code:

```
auth1 = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth1.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

class StreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
    def on_status(self, tweet):
        print tweet.text

    def on_error(self, status_code):
        print 'Error: ' + repr(status_code)
        return False

    def on_data(self, data):
        print 'Ok! Inserting Data.'
        from pymongo import MongoClient
        client = MongoClient()
        client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
        db = client.test
        test_id = db.twittertest.insert(json.loads(data))

l = StreamListener()
streamer = tweepy.Stream(auth=auth1, listener=l)
streamer.sample()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find out what the current `dbpath` is set to by using the [`getCmdLineOpts` command](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/getCmdLineOpts/).

For example, using the `mongo` shell:

```
db.adminCommand('getCmdLineOpts');
```

Specifically, you will find the `dbpath` as:

```
db.adminCommand('getCmdLineOpts').parsed.dbpath
```

If there is no `dbpath` set via the configuration, the default directory is `/data/db` on Linux/OS X or `C:\data\db` on Windows.

Comment: OK. I did this but apparently the above code is either doing nothing or saving somewhere else. I am not sure what is the issue.

Comment: Hrm, so no output from `db.adminCommand('getCmdLineOpts')`?  What does `db.version()` return?

Comment: There is output, but the files from the above code are not showing up there. It shows /opt/local/bin/mongod as the path but the above code does not save anything there. So I am wondering what's happening

Comment: If there is a `dbpath` value in the `getCmdLineOpts` output, this is where you should find your data files. Otherwise they will be in the default location of `/data/db`. What version of MongoDB did `db.version()` report?

Comment: 2.4.8 I am wondering if there is something wrong with the code, although I don't see anything obviously wrong. I can see the output at the terminal window but it's not being saved into db. Actually, no db is created at all

Comment: Have you tried inserting into a database from the `mongo` shell?  If all your databases are empty, perhaps the problem is unrelated to where the DB files live.  With MongoDB 2.4.8 there should at least be some `local.*` files created in the `dbpath`, though.

Comment: So, I went into mongo shell and deleted test database that existed there, ran my code and now it dreated test.0, test.1 and test.ns files. I guess that should be it?

Comment: I am really confused. I used to work with mysql and thought mongodb would be much easier to use for this purpose but I am a bit lost. How do I access tes1. test2 etc

Comment: The `test.*` files are used to store the `test` database. Your best bet would be to have a quick run through the [Getting Started tutorial](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/getting-started/). [MongoDB University](https://university.mongodb.com) also offers regular free online courses for developers and DBAs. The M101P course uses Python :)

Comment: I think I figured it out. Test is the database and twittertest is the collection. Thanks a lot though! You helped me a lot. I marked the question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what *ix you are using, consider trying lsof -p or fuser.

```
$ sudo lsof -p $$
[sudo] password for dstromberg:
COMMAND   PID       USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF     NODE NAME
bash    20786 dstromberg  cwd    DIR    8,6     4096 27525623 /home/dstromberg/src/outside-questions/subprocess
bash    20786 dstromberg  rtd    DIR    8,1     4096        2 /
bash    20786 dstromberg  txt    REG    8,1   975488   130366 /bin/bash
bash    20786 dstromberg  mem    REG    8,1    47616   130322 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.13.so
bash    20786 dstromberg  mem    REG    8,1    43552   130334 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.13.so
bash    20786 dstromberg  mem    REG    8,1    89056   130332 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl-2.13.so
bash    20786 dstromberg  mem    REG    8,1    31584   130324 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_compat-2.13.so
bash    20786 dstromberg  mem    REG    8,1  1595408   130328 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.13.so
bash    20786 dstromberg  mem    REG    8,1    14768   130321 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.13.so
bash    20786 dstromberg  mem    REG    8,1   167952   130362 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5.9
bash    20786 dstromberg  mem    REG    8,1   136936   130331 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.13.so
bash    20786 dstromberg  mem    REG    8,1   256360   103590 /usr/lib/locale/sw_KE/LC_CTYPE
bash    20786 dstromberg  mem    REG    8,1  1170770   103592 /usr/lib/locale/sw_KE/LC_COLLATE
bash    20786 dstromberg  mem    REG    8,1       54   103594 /usr/lib/locale/sw_KE/LC_NUMERIC
bash    20786 dstromberg  mem    REG    8,1     2454   105234 /usr/lib/locale/en_US.utf8/LC_TIME
bash    20786 dstromberg  mem    REG    8,1      286   105233 /usr/lib/locale/en_US.utf8/LC_MONETARY
bash    20786 dstromberg  mem    REG    8,1       57   105231 /usr/lib/locale/en_US.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/SYS_LC_MESSAGES
bash    20786 dstromberg  mem    REG    8,1       34   103621 /usr/lib/locale/en_PH.utf8/LC_PAPER
bash    20786 dstromberg  mem    REG    8,1       77   104457 /usr/lib/locale/yi_US.utf8/LC_NAME
bash    20786 dstromberg  mem    REG    8,1      155   105232 /usr/lib/locale/en_US.utf8/LC_ADDRESS
bash    20786 dstromberg  mem    REG    8,1       59   104451 /usr/lib/locale/yi_US.utf8/LC_TELEPHONE
bash    20786 dstromberg  mem    REG    8,1       23   104449 /usr/lib/locale/yi_US.utf8/LC_MEASUREMENT
bash    20786 dstromberg  mem    REG    8,1    26066       73 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gconv/gconv-modules.cache
bash    20786 dstromberg  mem    REG    8,1      373   105235 /usr/lib/locale/en_US.utf8/LC_IDENTIFICATION
bash    20786 dstromberg    0r   CHR    5,0      0t0     1036 /dev/tty
bash    20786 dstromberg    1w   CHR    5,0      0t0     1036 /dev/tty
bash    20786 dstromberg    2w   CHR    5,0      0t0     1036 /dev/tty
bash    20786 dstromberg  255w   CHR    5,0      0t0     1036 /dev/tty
```

...where "$$" is some pid, EG a pid from your mongo process(es).